# navigator.sendBeacon with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to send a `POST` request on the `beforeunload` event using `navigator.sendBeacon`, but the data doesn't get to the PHP `$_POST`. I think this is because when using `navigator.sendBeacon` the header `Content-Type` is always set to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`, but in my case since I need to send a query string and therefore use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
var amountOfApples = 0;

...

addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
    navigator.sendBeacon("save.php", "key=apples&value=" + amountOfApples);
});
```

How can I do this and make sure the header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `php://input` and run it through [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Basically:

```
$MY_POST = null;
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $MY_POST);
```

Comment: "Warning
Using this function without the result parameter is highly DISCOURAGED and DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2."

Comment: Yea, sorry, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: I was just about to do that!

Comment: Nice, well do you know why navigator.sendBeacon doesnt support this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, because it's not meant to be a full-fledged XMLHttpRequest (or `fetch()` FWIW) replacement, but it's only there to serve the singe purpose of getting a tiny bit of data somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to check if there actually is any php://input in order to prevent errors from being thrown if someone would send a request with another header without any of this data?

Comment: Well, you can store the `file_get_contents()` in a variable and do a `strlen()` on it. Also check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`.

Answer (score 7):

`Content-Type` header that Beacon API use, depend on type of instance you pass to `sendBeacon` second parameter.

### application/x-www-form-urlencoded

To send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use `UrlSearchParams` instance.

```
var params = new URLSearchParams({
   key : 'apples',
   values : amountOfApples
});
navigator.sendBeacon(anUrl, params);
```

### multipart/form-data

To send `multipart/form-data` header, use `FormData` instance.

```
var params = new FormData();
params.append('key', 'apples');
params.append('value', amountOfApples);
navigator.sendBeacon(anUrl, params);
```

### application/json

To send `application/json` header, use `Blob` and set its type.

```
var data = {
   key : 'apples',
   values : amountOfApples
};

var params = new Blob(
    [JSON.stringify(data)], 
    {type : 'application/json'}
);
navigator.sendBeacon(anUrl, params);
```

Comment: _Chrome sends URLSearchParams as text/plain instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded due to [Bug 747787](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747787), so using a Blob may be necessary._ – taken from [Kevin](https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2019/07/30/more-robust-javascript-error-reporting/).